# how to validate field which consist tuple of strings with float type?

Tags: python, validation, tuples, marshmallow

I have such field

```
coordinates = Tuple(
        (Float(), Float()),
        required=True,
    )
```

inside coordinates two values: latitude and longitude

I should validate those fields follow this condition **'coords': ((-90.0, 90.0), (-180.0, 180.0))**

Does somebody know how to do it?
I use marshmallow library

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could write a validation function using the [`@validates`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#field-validators-as-methods) decorator:

```
from marshmallow import fields, Schema, validates, ValidationError


class CoordinatesSchema(Schema):
    coordinates = fields.Tuple(
        (fields.Float(), fields.Float()),
        required=True,
    )   

    @validates("coordinates")
    def validate_coordinates(self, value):
        if value[0] not in (-90.0, -180.0):
            raise ValidationError("The first coordinate can only be -90.0 or -180.0.")
        if value[1] not in (90.0, 180.0):
            raise ValidationError("The second coordinate can only be 90.0 or 180.0.")

    
coords = {"coordinates": (-90.0, 180.0)}
CoordinatesSchema().load(coords)  # OK

coords = {"coordinates": (70.0, 180.0)}
try:
    CoordinatesSchema().load(coords)  # ValidationError
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.messages)  # 'coordinates': ['The first coordinate can only be -90.0 or -180.0.']}
```

Note that with the above `validate_coordinates` function, if both the first and second coordinates are invalid, only the first coordinate would be reported as such. That could be fixed by adding an extra `if` that checks whether both coordinates are not valid.